Why Does This VForked Assembly Occur Sequentially?
I'm running NASM x86_64 bit assembly on WSL. I'd have expected syscall_vfork to execute processes in parallel, yet it simply runs the child, then the parent.
bits 64
default rel

%include "stringfns.asm" ; basic print functionality

section .data
count: dw 0

section .text
global main

main:
    mov r15, 0
    spawner:
                mov rax, 58
            syscall

        cmp rax, 0
        je child

        call debug ; prints 0\n, occurs after child has finished

        inc r15
        cmp r15, 16 
        jne spawner

        jmp exit

    child:
        mov r15, 0
        .loop:
            inc r15
            cmp r15, 1000 ; execute child for some amount of time
            jne .loop   
        inc word [count]

        xor rsi, rsi
        mov si, [count]
        call iprintln ; prints integer in rsi

    exit:
        mov rax, 60
        mov rdi, 0
        syscall

I've also set max parallel threads to sixteen, without effect

"runs the parent, then the child" - the comments in your code say child then parent, which is also what the documentation says to expect.

See the man page - the description of the vfork() system call is "create a child process and block parent".  So what you're seeing is the intended, documented behavior.
Once upon a time, vfork() would run the parent and child concurrently while sharing an address space, but this caused a lot of problems, so Linux changed it so as to block the parent.  If you read something that told you differently, it's obsolete and you might not want to use that resource anymore.
If you want to copy the address space instead of sharing it, use fork().  If you want to share the address space and run concurrently, so that you're creating threads instead of processes, you need to use clone(), or better, the higher-level and more-portable pthread_* functions.
